# javascript - check if element directly contains any text

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if an element contains any text directly. By directly I mean: not through its children.

```
<div id="case1"></div>
<div id="case2">text-in-div</div>
<div id="case3">
    <p>text-in-p</p>
</div>
<div id="case4">
    text-in-div
    <p>text-in-p</p>
</div>
<div id="case5">
    <p>text-in-p</p>
    text-in-div
</div>
<div id="case6">
    <p>text-in-p</p>
    text-in-div
    <p>text-in-p</p>
</div>

<script>
    function containsTextDirectly(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        //what comes here?
    }

    console.log(containsTextDirectly("case1")); //false
    console.log(containsTextDirectly("case2")); //true
    console.log(containsTextDirectly("case3")); //false
    console.log(containsTextDirectly("case4")); //true
    console.log(containsTextDirectly("case5")); //true
    console.log(containsTextDirectly("case6")); //true

</script>
```

Obviously I could check it programmatically (remove children and see if the elements becomes empty..) but I am searching for a more optimal (elegant) solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for text nodes directly under the element:

```
return Array.prototype.some.call(element.childNodes, function(child) {
    return child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
})
```

If you want to make sure the text nodes are non-empty (to give the "correct" answer in your case3) then

```
    return child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && /\S/.test(child.nodeValue);
```

where `/\S/.test` tests for the presence of at least one non-white-space character.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want “ Any String ” and wants to ignore all the child element? Well, here is a simple solution using jQuery.

```
<script>
    $("#foo")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();    //get the text of element
</script>
```

We clone the element that you want text of, then remove all the child elements from this cloned element and then returns the text of element.