# Check if there's some text inside an element

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an If...Else statement and need to check if the element has innerHTML / textContent. 
Like this:

```
  if (<span class="event"> *yet has some text inside*) {do smth}
  else {do smth else};
```

So, how do I do that using Javascript?
Please, help!

**UPD!** I have dynamically changing content, and

```
 element.innerHTML
```

seems not working after I put some text inside my < span >. I mean it still thinks the < span > is empty. Any cure for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192623/checking-whether-an-html-element-contains-primitive-text or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011053/javascript-check-if-element-directly-contains-any-text

Comment: Do you want to check if there is any type of content what so ever or if it directly contains text as a child or text in child elements?

Comment: @Xotic750 It is about any text typed inside < span > < /span > tags.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov So if it contained, for example, another `<span>` but no text then you want a `false` or if it contained another `<span>` which had text this would also be `false`. You would only get a `true` if there is text as a child of `<span class="event">`?

Comment: @AlexandrBelov, this should work now : http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/gvpkhtxo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `innerHTML` of the span using `document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName");`. You need to `index` it as you may have more than one element with same class name. Add text inside `span` dynamically on button click. And check again if it effects the output. Try this way,

***HTML :***

```
<span class="event"></span>

<button id="addTextButton">Add Text In Span</button>

<button id="removeSpanTextButton">Empty Span</button>

<button id="checkSpanButton">Check Span Content</button>
```

***javaScript :***

```
var spanContent = document.getElementsByClassName("event")[0];

checkSpanButton.onclick = function(){
    if(spanContent.innerHTML == ""){
        alert("Span is empty..");
    }
    else{
        alert("Span Text : " + spanContent.innerHTML);
    }
};

// dynamically add text
addTextButton.onclick = function(){
    spanContent.innerHTML = "Added This Text.";
};

removeSpanTextButton.onclick = function(){
    spanContent.innerHTML = "";
};
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/0m8eo57m/)

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty simple:

```
if (element.innerHTML) {
    // element has content
} else {
    // element is empty
}
```

Comment: According to logic it must work. But I have dynamically changing content. And when I add some text inside the span (element.innerHTML) seems not to notice it (maybe because primary it had no text inside). Any solution for that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly then it shouldn't matter. The `innerHTML` property returns a representation of the content of an `HTMLElement`, whether its text or descendant elements. If there is anything inside the element (including an empty space), then the condition will be false and the `else` block will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

All current browsers support `textContent`, down to IE9.

`textContent` will return a clean version of all of the actual text, stripped of intervening tags. Unlike the less standard `innerText`, it is unaffected by changes in appearance brought about by CSS.

The simple solution is:

```js
if (element.textContent) {
    //  do something
}
else {
    //  do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('event')[0];
if(element.innerHTML){
  //do something
} else{
  // do other things
}
```

If you want to iterate over all element that has class event then use:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('event');
for(var i=0;i<element.length;i++){
  if(element[i].innerHTML){
    //do something
  } else{
    // do other things
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to do it with Javascript, not with JQuery)

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("event");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].innerHTML)...
}
```

You can access HTML elements from JS with many [ways](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp). Once you have accessed yours element, you can just `if(elem.innerHTML)`.

```
//P.S.
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('event')[0];
```

Don't use that advice below without checking array size.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method to innerHTML

```
if(document.getElementById("element_id").lastChild) {
    //Has content
}
else {
    //No content
}
```